# lxc Container does not start

Tags: 16.04, lxc, container

I am trying to run an lxc container on Ubuntu 16.10 with the following configurations:

```
lxc.utsname = cont
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = bridge
lxc.network.ipv4 = 10.0.0.10/24
```

The bridge is already up and running. I create the container using xenial template as following:

```
lxc-create -f lxc-veth.conf -t download -n cont -- --dist ubuntu --release xenial --arch amd64 --no-validate
```

Then I start the container:

```
lxc-start -n cont /bin/bash --logfile log.txt
```

I get the following errors:

```
  lxc-start 20161114114122.026 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:start:1439 - No such file or directory - failed to exec /lib/lxc cont
  lxc-start 20161114124122.026 ERROR    lxc_sync - sync.c:__sync_wait:57 - An error occurred in another process (expected sequence number 5)
  lxc-start 20161114124122.026 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:__lxc_start:1354 - failed to spawn 'cont'
  lxc-start 20161114124127.568 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - tools/lxc_start.c:main:344 - The container failed to start.
  lxc-start 20161114124127.568 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - tools/lxc_start.c:main:346 - To get more details, run the container in foreground mode.
  lxc-start 20161114124127.568 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - tools/lxc_start.c:main:348 - Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.
```

I am not able to find out which file is missing. So what is the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists in the last command `lxc-start`, the command should be:

```
lxc-start -n cont --logfile bla.txt -- /bin/bash
```

Basically there is not need to run `/bin/bash` since when I attach the container I will have shell access